# Auto refresh and alert if changes

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

Hello im working in javascript code with extension tampermonkey to auto refresh and check if there is available dates in appointement website if true then alert

this code of auto refresh

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 50*1000);
```

code source of available dates

[available dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtWvd.png)

[available dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzmlH.png)

code source of unavailable dates

[unavailable dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td2se.png)

[unavailable dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YffnV.png)

check and alert code

`if ((document.getElementsByClassName('day activeClass').length !==0) { new Audio('http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=287&type=mp3').play();clearInterval(gun);}`

the page is auto refreshing but not alert me when there is a changes
can you guide me what should i do to make this code work and thanks you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

location.reload() refreshes the whole webpage. Previous state or data is not maintained. Let say if you have set a flag `let changeInDates = false` and after getting data, you change it to `true` and call `location.reload()`, it will throw all the data in garbage and restart the execution from top and execute `let changeInDates = false` again.

I'd suggest getting data over an ajax request and then resend the request in regular intervals. This way, state of rest of page is maintained.